# Modx Revolution Installation Fails

Tags: modx, modx-revolution

I am trying to install Modx Revolution on an Nginx server I have, but the installation fails and results in an empty screen after I select the "Install" button during setup. The installation itself runs without any problems until it reaches this point, so I'm really scratching my head here. I've ran through the Modx forums numerous times to no avail.

A few things to note:

The SQL database fills up with the tables generated by Modx but without anything in the users table.

I've tried adding write permissions to ALL files recursively in the Modx directory, as well as setting 777 permissions and changing user/group ownership of every file.

I've ensured the nginx configuration script is identical to one that is being used on another box that is running properly.

The empty screen appears when the URL reads "index.php?action=install" at the end.

If anybody knows of anything I haven't tried or am blindly ignoring, I would greatly appreciate it.

Thanks!

EDIT: I ran the setup in Chrome, and I am actually getting an HTTP 500, unable to handle the request error.

EDIT #2: In the error log for nginx I receive the following lines:

"directory index of "[directory]" is forbidden, client: [client], server: [server], request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", host: "[hostname]"

"FastCGI sent in stderr: "Primary script unknown" while reading response header from upstream"

"connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client [client], server [server], request: "GET /setup/index.php?action=summary HTTP/1.1"

Comment: What database and which version are you using?

Comment: you are probably getting php errors - review your error logs.

Comment: @Jako I'm using MySql 5.6.33 for the database.

Comment: @Sean Kimball I just checked the error logs again for nginx, and am getting a few lines which I will add in a second edit statement in my post.

Comment: @hRdCoder should be no issue. 5.7 has actually some issues with MODX 2.5.1 and below.

Comment: @Jako I've been using 5.6, but I might try using another version of SQL and see if anything changes with the result.

Comment: try running php as a module ~ not as a cgi.  I've had issues in the past trying to run modx on php as a cgi ...

Comment: I just figured it out actually. Turns out that Revolution requires that SimpleXML is enabled, even though the installer just shows a warning if it is not. Thanks everybody, for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just figured it out actually. Turns out that ModX Revolution requires that SimpleXML is enabled, even though the installer just shows a warning if it is not. The installer continued as normal after I installed, and then enabled the SimpleXML extension for PHP.